# Solving puzzle with sum

Tags: list-manipulation, puzzle

My dad really likes to play this kind of puzzle. And I've tried to help you get the values to my level of knowledge.

The puzzle looks like this:

[image: Imagem1]

The rule is to use numbers from 1 to 9, but it is not allowed to have repeated numbers in the same sum.

This prohibition I failed to create a logic to get the values.

So to figure out the values I had to go testing values visually.

**Code:**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Empty boxes

```
a5 = ■; a6 = ■; b5 = ■; b6 = ■; c4 = ■; c5 = ■; c6 = ■; d1 = ■; e3 = ■; e6 = ■; f2 = ■; g4 = ■;
```

Defined values

```
e1 = 7; e2 = 9; g2 = 2; a4 = 1; b4 = 3; d6 = 5; f1 = 9;
```

Solution

```
Solve[
   a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 == 13 &&
    b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 == 16 &&
    c1 + c2 + c3 == 14 &&
    d2 + d3 + d4 + d5 + d6 == 18 &&
    e4 + e5 == 12 &&
    f3 + f4 + f5 + f6 == 14 &&
    g1 + g2 + g3 == 15 &&
    g5 + g6 == 14 &&
    a1 + b1 + c1 == 13 &&
    a2 + b2 + c2 + d2 + e2 == 32 &&
    a3 + b3 + c3 + d3 == 11 &&
    e1 + f1 + g1 == 24 &&
    f3 + g3 == 11 &&
    d4 + e4 + f4 == 16 &&
    d5 + e5 + f5 + g5 == 11 &&
    f6 + g6 == 12,
   {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d2, d3, d4, d5, e4, e5, g1, 
    g3, g5, g6, f3, f4, f5, f6}
   ] /. Rule -> Set;
```

Manual attempt

```
g5 = 5; d4 = 3; e4 = 9; a1 = 7; b1 = 5; a2 = 2; b2 = 6; c2 = 8;
```

Matrix

```
{
 {a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1},
 {a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2},
 {a3, b3, c3, d3, e3, f3, g3},
 {a4, b4, c4, d4, e4, f4, g4},
 {a5, b5, c5, d5, e5, f5, g5},
 {a6, b6, c6, d6, e6, f6, g6}
}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  7 & 5 & 1 & \blacksquare  & 7 & 9 & 8 \\
>  2 & 6 & 8 & 7 & 9 & \blacksquare  & 2 \\
>  3 & 2 & 5 & 1 & \blacksquare  & 6 & 5 \\
>  1 & 3 & \blacksquare  & 3 & 9 & 4 & \blacksquare  \\
>  \blacksquare  & \blacksquare  & \blacksquare  & 2 & 3 & 1 & 5 \\
>  \blacksquare  & \blacksquare  & \blacksquare  & 5 & \blacksquare  & 3 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

The result is as follows:

[image]

**EDIT**

I'm trying to create the game board using [Feyre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136257/37895) solution. It would be more or less like this?

```
linhas = 7; colunas = 9;
LH = {{0, #}, {colunas, #}} & /@ Range[0, linhas];
LV = {{#, 0}, {#, linhas}} & /@ Range[0, colunas];
LO = {
   {{0.5, 2}, {0.5, 6}},
   {{3.5, 0}, {3.5, 3}},
   {{5.5, 0}, {5.5, 1}},
   {{8.5, 3}, {8.5, 6}},
   {{1, 6.5}, {4, 6.5}},
   {{5, 6.5}, {8, 6.5}},
   {{4, 5.5}, {5, 5.5}},
   {{6, 4.5}, {7, 4.5}},
   {{5, 3.5}, {6, 3.5}},
   {{7, 2.5}, {8, 2.5}}
   };

pAlist = {1.5, # + .5} & /@ Reverse[Range[0, 5]];
pBlist = {2.5, # + .5} & /@ Reverse[Range[0, 5]];
pClist = {3.5, # + .5} & /@ Reverse[Range[0, 5]];
pDlist = {4.5, # + .5} & /@ Reverse[Range[0, 5]];
pElist = {5.5, # + .5} & /@ Reverse[Range[0, 5]];
pFlist = {6.5, # + .5} & /@ Reverse[Range[0, 5]];
pGlist = {7.5, # + .5} & /@ Reverse[Range[0, 5]];
For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++, 
  ToExpression["pA" <> ToString[i] <> "=" <> ToString[pAlist[[i]]]]];
For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++, 
  ToExpression["pB" <> ToString[i] <> "=" <> ToString[pBlist[[i]]]]];
For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++, 
  ToExpression["pC" <> ToString[i] <> "=" <> ToString[pClist[[i]]]]];
For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++, 
  ToExpression["pD" <> ToString[i] <> "=" <> ToString[pDlist[[i]]]]];
For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++, 
  ToExpression["pE" <> ToString[i] <> "=" <> ToString[pElist[[i]]]]];
For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++, 
  ToExpression["pF" <> ToString[i] <> "=" <> ToString[pFlist[[i]]]]];
For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++, 
  ToExpression["pG" <> ToString[i] <> "=" <> ToString[pGlist[[i]]]]];

textHold = {
   Text[e1, pE1],
   Text[e2, pE2],
   Text[g2, pG2],
   Text[a4, pA4],
   Text[b4, pB4],
   Text[d6, pD6],
   Text[f1, pF1]
   };

value = ToExpression["s2[[1," <> ToString[#] <> "]]"] & /@ Range[23];
pos = {pA1, pA2, pA3, pB1, pB2, pB3, pC1, pC2, pC3, pD2, pD3, pD4, 
   pD5, pE4, pE5, pG1, pG3, pG5, pG6, pF3, pF4, pF5, pF6};
textResp = MapThread[Text, {value, pos}];

Graphics[{Map[Line, Join[LH, LV]], Dashed, Map[Line, LO], 
  FontSize -> 20, textResp, Red, textHold}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have identified two solutions, can you check they're both correct? My second one is the one you had.

Comment: What is the question? To find concrete solutions, to give a method to find solutions for the general problem, or to make a convenient interface (board) for the puzzle?

Comment: @AntonAntonov I've already had an answer on how to get the solution, but I'm also interested in suggestions for a similar puzzle with the image. I think the lines I made were unprofessional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can set a range limitation and define integers as the domain, however, if we use all restrictions, `Solve[]` just hangs. It is best to get all possible solutions first, then restrict them.

```
eqs = Flatten@{1 + a1 + a2 + a3 == 13, 3 + b1 + b2 + b3 == 16, 
    c1 + c2 + c3 == 14, 5 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5 == 18, e4 + e5 == 12, 
    f3 + f4 + f5 + f6 == 14, 2 + g1 + g3 == 15, g5 + g6 == 14, 
    a1 + b1 + c1 == 13, 9 + a2 + b2 + c2 + d2 == 32, 
    a3 + b3 + c3 + d3 == 11, 16 + g1 == 24, f3 + g3 == 11, 
    d4 + e4 + f4 == 16, d5 + e5 + f5 + g5 == 11, f6 + g6 == 12, 
    Thread[0 < vars < 10]};
vars = {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3, d2, d3, d4, d5, e4, e5, 
   g1, g3, g5, g6, f3, f4, f5, f6};
a5 = ■; a6 = ■; b5 = ■; b6 = ■; c4 = ■; c5 = ■; c6 = ■; d1 = ■; e3 = ■; e6 = ■; f2 = ■; g4 = ■;
```

Solve:

```
s = Solve[eqs, vars, Integers];
Length@s
```

> `16756`

Now select for those that don't have repeat integers, there seem to be two solutions:

```
s2 = Select[
   vars /. s, #[[1]] != #[[2]] != #[[3]] != 
      1 && #[[4]] != #[[5]] != #[[6]] != 
      3 && #[[7]] != #[[8]] != #[[9]] && #[[10]] != #[[11]] != 
#[[12]] != #[[13]] != 
      5 && #[[14]] != #[[15]] && #[[20]] != #[[21]] != #[[22]] != 
#[[23]] && #[[16]] != #[[17]] != 
      2 && #[[18]] != #[[19]] && #[[1]] != #[[4]] != #[[7]] && 
#[[2]] != #[[5]] != #[[8]] != #[[10]] != 
      9 && #[[3]] != #[[6]] != #[[9]] != #[[11]] && 
     7 != 9 != #[[16]] && #[[20]] != #[[17]] && #[[12]] != #[[14]] 
!= #[[21]] && #[[13]] != #[[15]] != #[[22]] != #[[18]] &];
Length@s2
```

> `2`

```
{{a1, b1, c1, d1, 7, 9, g1}, {a2, b2, c2, d2, 9, f2, 2}, {a3, b3, 
    c3, d3, e3, f3, g3}, {1, 3, c4, d4, e4, f4, g4}, {a5, b5, c5, 
    d5, e5, f5, g5}, {a6, b6, c6, 5, e6, f6, g6}} /. 
  Thread[vars -> s2[[1]]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
{{a1, b1, c1, d1, 7, 9, g1}, {a2, b2, c2, d2, 9, f2, 2}, {a3, b3, 
    c3, d3, e3, f3, g3}, {1, 3, c4, d4, e4, f4, g4}, {a5, b5, c5, 
    d5, e5, f5, g5}, {a6, b6, c6, 5, e6, f6, g6}} /. 
  Thread[vars -> s2[[2]]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Note that you can find the lists of which positions can't match in values and the values they can't match with:

```
var = Flatten[Position[vars, #] & /@ Variables[eqs[[#, 1]]]] & /@ 
  Range[15]
con = Select[eqs[[#, 1]], IntegerQ] & /@ Range[15]
```

> `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13}, {14, 15}, {20, 21,
>      22, 23}, {16, 17}, {18, 19}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8, 10}, {3, 6, 9, 
>     11}, {16}, {20, 17}, {12, 14, 21}, {13, 15, 22, 18}}`
>
> `{1, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0}`

Answer (score 6):

I haven't solved the numerical aspect of your problem, I will have to return to it a little later. However here is some code which will process the image into a computable format, ready for a solution to create and solve the equations.

```
bimg = Binarize[img, 0.95];
ip = ImagePartition[bimg, {Scaled[1/9], Scaled[1/7]}];
ipc = Map[ImageCrop[#, 210 {1, 1}] &, ip, {2}];

(*Train a classifier for test recognition*)
characters = 
  Flatten[Table[
    ImageCrop[
        Rasterize[Text[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Century Gothic"]], 
         ImageSize -> size]] -> # & /@ (ToString /@ 
       Range[45]), {size, {20, 30, 40, 50}}]];
simpleOcr = Classify[characters];

(*Dirty but does the trick for now*)
vals2[img_] := Module[{subimgs, v, p},

  subimgs = {
    ImageCrop[img, {210, 100}, Bottom],
    ImageCrop[img, {210, 100}, Top],
    ImageCrop[img, {100, 210}, Left],
    ImageCrop[img, {100, 210}, Right]
    };

  v = N /@ Mean /@ Flatten /@ ImageData /@ subimgs;

  If[v == {0., 0., 0., 0.}, Black,
   If[v == {1., 1., 1., 1.}, White,
    p = Flatten[Position[v, 1.]];
    If[Length[p] == 1,
     simpleOcr@ImageCrop[
       subimgs[[{2, 1, 4, 3}]][[
         p[[1]]
         ]]
       ],
     Style[simpleOcr@ImageCrop[img], Red]
     ]
    ]
   ]

  ]

Grid[
 Map[vals2, ipc, {2}]
 ]
```

[image]